# Reflection does not see companion of subclass case class when defined in companion of extending trait

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Given a code which takes a type, takes it's known direct subclasses, filters the ones that are case classes and then takes the companion of that case class:

```
def firstSubclassWithCompanion[T: TypeTag]: String = {
  val superclass = implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
  val caseClass = superclass.knownDirectSubclasses.map(_.asClass).filter(_.isCaseClass).head
  s"case class $caseClass has companion ${caseClass.companion}"
}
```

With a simple example

```
sealed trait With
case class WithCase() extends With
```

It gives the expected return

```
> firstSubclassWithCompanion[With]
"class WithCase has companion object WithCase"
```

As `With` trait has a `WithCase` subclass, which is case class that has a companion object (defined by compiler).

However, given the following example, where the subclass is defined in the companion object of the inheriting trait:

```
sealed trait Without
object Without {
  case class WithoutCase() extends Without
}
```

It doesn't return the companion object

```
> firstSubclassWithCompanion[Without]
"class WithoutCase has companion <none>"
```

It works fine if it's defined in other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugs should be reported at https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

A workaround is to use `caseClass.owner.typeSignature.decl(caseClass.name)` instead of `caseClass.companion`.

Another workaround is to translate this runtime-reflection code into a macro (compile-time reflection). Since all the classes here are defined at compile time it makes sense to use a macro.

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def firstSubclassWithCompanion[T]: String = macro firstSubclassWithCompanionImpl[T]

def firstSubclassWithCompanionImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val superclass = weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
  val caseClass = superclass.knownDirectSubclasses.map(_.asClass).filter(_.isCaseClass).head
  val res = s"case class $caseClass has companion ${caseClass.companion}"
  q"$res"
}
```